# Corosync and Pacemaker deployment

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, pacemaker, corosync, postgresql-9.3

I'm currently working on a deployment architecture for a Postgres HA 1 Master/ 1 Slave scenario. After reading lots and lots of documentation I've decided to start using Pacemaker in conjunction with Corosync on Ubuntu LTS.

What's currently not clear to me is if Corosync and Pacemaker is supposed to run on the actual database hosts or on nodes dedicated solely to managing the actual cluster nodes. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to run them on the DB hosts as well as they are required to manage the resources (which are the database instances in your case). I assume that you could also create "remote resources" and remotely manage them but I'd say it is rather inefficient.